# can anyone help me resolve this, in my console browser chrome when running laravel 10, error about websocket with laravel 10

Tags: javascript, websocket, laravel-blade, reload, ws

WebSocket connection to 'ws://127.0.0.1:5500//ws' failed:
init @ reload.js:22
(anonymous) @ reload.js:65

could help me step by step? I don't know if that's why the image I want to display can't use asset()
this is error image can't display from console : (failed)net::ERR_INVALID_HTTP_RESPONSE and me use "XAMPP" just apache and "MYSQL". I'm sorry if me have mistake because me so beginner

Comment: do you have a websocket server listening at 127.0.0.1:5500? also, it'd be `ws://127.0.0.1:5500/ws` rather than `ws://127.0.0.1:5500//ws` ... I wonder if that extra `/` is the issue